# Can someone explain me why was this a split pot? texas hold'em

Tags: poker-texas-holdem, split

I would want to ask you why was this a split pot.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You get the highest possible five card combination. The remaining hole cards are lower than the A and K on the table -- best five cards then is Three of a Kind in 10s, Ace, King.  Other cards are ignored, so both players *have the same hand*.